# Sockets vs web service .NET (file updater)

Tags: c#

I'm going to make a program (c# .NET) that downloads files from a server (basically a file updater) and I'll have around 1,000 clients downloading files ( from 1 to 10 each client) this files are small ( from 100k to 2.5 MB). So what kind of communication would you recommend? sockets? web service? WSE 3 MTOM? or prob another suggestion? thanks

Comment: Interesting.  Problems any way you go here, can the 'server' run inside IIS?

Answer (score 4):

Any reason not to just download the files from a web server, using the built-in [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.95).aspx) class?  On the server-side, depending on what you needed, you could either throw the files out statically onto the file system, or use an ASHX handler to "create" them dynamically.

Steer well away from native sockets.  You can do it, and it's fast, but all you'll end up doing is reinventing the wheel.  IIS or Apache will give you fundamentally identical performance as raw sockets, for the tiniest fraction of the investment in time and resources.

Comment: Agreed, don't reinvent the wheel. Use IIS or similar to serve the files and use WebClient to get them.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) class, which is quite approachable.  But if I were expecting 1,000 clients hitting me on a regular basis, I'd set up a real Web server, as others have suggested.